# settimeout in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wicket

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery not proceeding to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139924/jquery-not-proceeding-to-next-page)

issue: dynamic page loading issue in IE6/7. click following link, it works fine in firefox but issue is in IE. click on new customer street rue maes, no: 00, postal code:1000 and click continue. A dynamic image can be seen in FF but not in IE.
https://admit.belgacom.be/WCE/ESW/selectBundle/productId/hbs_pstn_int_comf

```
 static private class SafeSubmitBehaviour extends AbstractBehavior{
    public void onRendered( Component component ) {
      super.onRendered( component );      
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(200);
      buffer.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" >\n");
      buffer.append("var input = $(\"input[name='submitted']\");\n");
      buffer.append("if (input.val() == \"false\") {\n"); 
      buffer.append("  input.val(\"true\");\n"); 
      buffer.append("  setTimeout(function(){ $(\"#").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("\").submit()}, 100);\n"); 
      buffer.append("}\n");
      buffer.append("else {\n $(\"#toHide\").hide();\n}"); 
      component.getResponse().write(buffer);
    }  
  }
```

HTML source code output:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> var input = $("input[name='submitted'");if (input.val() == "false") { input.val("true"); setTimeout(function(){ $("#safeForm15").submit()}, 100);}else { $("#toHide").hide();}</SCRIPT>
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
    <img style="display: inline" src="img/load.gif" />
    <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix">
        <input type="hidden" wicket:id="submitted" value="false" />
        </form>
 </div>
```

Issue i feel like settimeout. Can i use jquery function instead of settimeout. I use jquery-1.3.2. 
Can i use BlockUI plugin. how can i replace this code? or any other simplerway?