# jquery animation issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery not proceeding to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139924/jquery-not-proceeding-to-next-page)

I have jquery, it works fine in FF, but issue is with IE, image is loading but animation is not happening.

html source code:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">  
   var $ = jQuery.noConflict();  
   $('#toHide').show().doTimeout(100,function() { 
   $('#toHide').find('safeForma3').submit();});
</SCRIPT>
```

html code:

```
<div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
    <img style="display: inline" src="img/load.gif" />
    <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix">
        <input type="hidden" wicket:id="submitted" value="false" />
    </form>
</div>
```

goto this link https://admit.belgacom.be/WCE/ESW/selectBundle/productId/hbs_pstn_int_comf and click new customer, street as rue maes, no as 7, postcode as 1000. click continue, in FF iamge with animation is happening, but in IE only images are shown but no animation is happening.